# How to conditionally output part of a view using a helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, let's say I have the following part of a view:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete")
</td>
```

I only want this to be available to a user if they have a certain permission - `DeleteItems`.  A couple ways to do this would be to wrap the link with an `if` statement or to make an overload for the `ActionLink` helper that takes in a set of permissions.

`If` version:

```
@if (User.HasPermission(Permissions.DeleteItems))
{
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")
</td>
}
```

Overload version:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", Permissions.DeleteItems)
</td>
```

Cool - I think the obvious winner here is the overload.

However, what if the area I want to block off is larger?

```
<div class="deleteWrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @item.Id })
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

The `If` version still works, of course, but I don't want to have `@if (User.Has...(...))` everywhere in my views.  What I like is the syntax of `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    ...
}
```

However, `BeginForm` [only adds to the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121065/how-does-using-htmlhelper-beginform-work) - it doesn't actually do anything with the piece of the view in between the brackets.  Is there a way to **remove** the markup inside the brackets using a helper?

```
@using(Html.ShowIf(...))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You mean remove the markup inside the brackets using `BeginForm` or with your helper like `@using (Html.YourHelper()) { ... }`?

Comment: @asymptoticFault: With a helper like `@using(...)` - I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here is an example that works only for `Razor`:

```
@using (this.BeginPermissionScope(Permissions.DeleteItems))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home"))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
}
```

`C#` Code:

```
public static class HtmlHelperPermissionScopeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Begin new rendering scope based on current user permissions
    /// </summary>
    public static IDisposable BeginPermissionScope(this WebViewPage webViewPage, Permissions permission)
    {
        var currentIdentity = webViewPage.User.Identity;
        bool userHasPermission = currentIdentity.HasPermission(permission);
        return new PermissionScopeHelper(webViewPage, !userHasPermission);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class that replaces current output stream with its own
    /// </summary>
    private sealed class PermissionScopeHelper : IDisposable
    {
        WebViewPage webViewPage;
        TextWriter oldWriter;
        TextWriter newWriter;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes helper class instance. If ignoreMarkupUntilDispose is set to true, then 
        /// all markup writen to response will be ignored
        /// </summary>
        public PermissionScopeHelper(WebViewPage page, bool ignoreMarkupUntilDispose)
        {
            if (ignoreMarkupUntilDispose)
            {
                webViewPage = page;
                newWriter = new StringWriter();

                // Replace output TextWriter for Write() and WriteLiteral() methods
                webViewPage.OutputStack.Push(newWriter);

                // Replace output TextWriter for all HtmlHelper and AjaxHelper extensions
                oldWriter = webViewPage.ViewContext.Writer;
                webViewPage.ViewContext.Writer = newWriter;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restore output TextWriters
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (webViewPage != null)
            {
                webViewPage.ViewContext.Writer = oldWriter;
                webViewPage.OutputStack.Pop();
                newWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, I was working out an example that was going to do something just like this.